# Problem using \tkzGetPoints

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm trying to draw a simple figure to illustrate a lesson on reflection.
I want to have a F, an axis and the F reflected.

So, I defined some points to draw the F and I tried using \tkzDefPointsBy[reflection=over ...].

As I understand it, you have to then use \tkzGetPoints to "really" define the reflected points (not sure of this). But is doesn't work...

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B, 1/2/C, 2/2/D, 2/3/E, 1/3/F, 1/4/G, 3/4/H, 3/5/I, 0/5/J, 1/-1/M, 5/7/N}
    \tkzDefPointsBy[reflection=over M--N](A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J){a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}
    \tkzGetPoints{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D) --(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(I)--(J)--cycle;
    \draw M--N;
    \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d) --(e)--(f)--(g)--(h)--(i)--(j)--cycle;
            
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result I get is "Package pgf Error : No shape named `tkzFirstPointResult' is known." and the same with tkzSecondPointResult.

I hope it was clear. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Remark: The documentation of `\tkzGetPoints` by itself is a bit confusing, but it can be understood more easily reading the example below it. Basically if the documentation of some **other** command mentions  "result is stored into `tkzFirstPointResult`" or similar, then it can be accessed with `tkzGetPoint` family of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't actually need `\tkzGetPoints` in this case :)

When you do e.g. `\tkzDefPointsBy[reflection=over M--N](A,B){a,b}` the reflections of `A` and `B` are named `a` and `b` respectively. If the `{}` had been empty, i.e. `\tkzDefPointsBy[reflection=over M--N](A,B){}`, the reflections of `A` and `B` would be named `A'` and `B'` respectively. So you never need `\tkzGetPoints` with `\tkzDefPointsBy`.

So by just removing the `\tkzGetPoints` line, and adding the missing parentheses in `\draw (M)--(N);`, you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 1/0/B, 1/2/C, 2/2/D, 2/3/E, 1/3/F, 1/4/G, 3/4/H, 3/5/I, 0/5/J, 1/-1/M, 5/7/N}
    \tkzDefPointsBy[reflection=over M--N](A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J){a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}
%    \tkzGetPoints{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D) --(E)--(F)--(G)--(H)--(I)--(J)--cycle;
    \draw (M)--(N); 
    \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(d) --(e)--(f)--(g)--(h)--(i)--(j)--cycle;
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer now :)
But what's the use of \tkzGetPoints then ?

Comment: @Kawahiem Other macros for defining points require it. The first example I find in the manual is `\tkzInterCC`.  Why the package author has decided to construct the package in this way I do not know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :)
Do you know how I can close the question since it had been answered ?

Comment: @Kawahiem Click the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: @Kawahiem When you define a (one) point, the result is stored in tkzPointresult and in some cases you don't have to keep the result and it avoids defining a new node.  So we use `tkzGetPoint` if we want to assign a name. With some macros, two points are defined (e.g. `tkzInterCC` there we use `\tkzGetPoints`. When a list of points is defined, the nodes are assigned directly.